# How I can execute to script when ssh sessions is exited?

Tags: ssh

.ssh/rc can execute script when user logged in.
But when user logged out with ssh, how it execute script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a trap to execute your script when the user logs out:

```
trap 'bash /path/to/yourscript.sh; exit' 0
```

If the shell is bash then any code you put in the `~/.bash_logout` file will be executed on logout. For csh, the file is .logout.

Another option would be to run a daemon like this:

```
setsid mydaemon.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

Which can execute your script at any time after the user has logged out.

Comment: Thanks John.  I use bash and can execute script with putting `~/.bash_logout`